# How to convert a list of integers into a matrix of these integers in F#

Tags: f#

I am getting my F#eet wet and having a hard time getting my head around simple concepts. Please oblige me by helping with this question, NOT homework!

Say I have a list `[1;2;3;4]`

How do I transform it into  list of all possible combinations of the list's elements:

`[(1,2);(1,3);(1,4);(2,3);(2,4);(3,4)]`?

What I have come up with:

```
 let tuples=
    let lst=[1;2;3;4]
    List.map (fun i->(i,i)) lst
```

Obviously this gives the wrong result, but how to proceed? Do I simply need to use the nested for loops approach that I would take writing this code in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use recursion to achieve this, I believe this is called the "cons pattern"

```
open NUnit.Framework
open Swensen.Unquote

let convert input =
    let rec loop remain acc =
        match remain with
        | x :: xs -> 
            let combos = xs |> List.map (fun i -> (x,i))
            loop xs (acc@combos)
        | x -> acc

    loop input []

[<Test>]
let TheTest () =
    let actual = convert [1;2;3;4]
    let expected = [(1,2);(1,3);(1,4);(2,3);(2,4);(3,4)]
    test <@ expected = actual @>
```

Comment: Agreed, this is exactly the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea would be this: for each element `x` of the list, produce a list of `x`-combinations by combining it with every element `y` that comes *after* `x` in the list.

To do this, you'd need to index the elements, so you can compare them in terms of coming before/after each other. For this you can use the `List.indexed` function:

```
let lst = [1;2;3;4]
let indexedLst = List.indexed lst
// indexedLst = [(0,1); (1,2); (2,3); (3,4)]
```

After we have the elements indexed, we can pick one element (together with its index) and produce a list of combinations of that element with every other element that comes after it:

```
let combineWithSuccessors (x_idx, x) = 
   [ for y_idx, y in indexedLst do 
       if y_idx > x_idx then yield (x, y) ]

// Or if you prefer not using list comprehensions:
let combineWithSuccessors (x_idx, x) = 
   indexedLst 
   |> List.filter (fun (y_idx, _) -> y_idx > x_idx)
   |> List.map (fun (_, y) -> (x, y))

// test it out:
combineWithSuccessors (2, 3) == [(3,4)]
combineWithSuccessors (0, 1) == [(1,2); (2,3); (3,4)]
```

Finally, generate such combinations list for every `x`, and concatenate all these lists in one:

```
let allCombinations = 
   indexedLst |> List.map combineWithSuccessors |> List.concat
```

And then put it all together:

```
let allCombinations lst =
    let indexedLst = List.indexed lst

    let combineWithSuccessors (x_idx, x) = 
        [ for y_idx, y in indexedLst do 
            if y_idx > x_idx then yield (x, y) ]

    indexedLst |> List.map combineWithSuccessors |> List.concat
```

Test it out:

```
allCombinations [1;2;3;4;5]
> [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (1, 5); (2, 3); (2, 4); (2, 5); (3, 4); (3, 5); (4, 5)]

allCombinations [5;7;1;2;3]
> [(5, 7); (5, 1); (5, 2); (5, 3); (7, 1); (7, 2); (7, 3); (1, 2); (1, 3); (2, 3)]
```

Comment: This solution also won't work for lists with duplicate elements.

Comment: Yes, it will. Try it.

Comment: I did. [1;2;3;4;4] |> allCombinations => two copies of (1,4),  two copies of (2,4) and two copies of (3,4).

Comment: @Soldalma Nobody specified what should happen with duplicates, so it's a matter of opinion whether or not this is correct behaviour. I certainly didn't see the word "set" anywhere, so I think this is correct behaviour.

Comment: If this is correct behavior why did you complain about my solutions? ("This solution won't work for lists with duplicate elements") They had exactly the same problem as yours: duplicate elements in the returned list.

Comment: @spender - Sorry, it was not you that complained. My mistake. My apologies to you and Fyodor Soikin.

Comment: Your original solution worked hallway: the first elements of the tuples would be kept duplicate, but second elements would be deduplicated. Your amended solution removes all duplicates completely, which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using library functions:

```
let tuples xs =
    let ys = List.distinct xs
    ys
    |> List.allPairs ys
    |> List.filter (fun (x, y) -> x < y)
[1..4] |> tuples
// val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4); (3, 4)]
```

Here is another solution based on list comprehensions:

```
let tuples' (xs: 'T list) =
    let ys = List.distinct xs
    let len1 = ys.Length - 1
    [for i in 0 .. len1 do for j in (i+1) .. len1 do yield (ys.[i], ys.[j])]
[1..4] |> tuples'
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4); (3, 4)]
```

(The type annotation is needed)

Comment: This solution won't work for lists with duplicate elements.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Thanks. I edited the answer and fixed the problem.

Comment: No, you haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: How could the problem not be fixed given that the list that the original functions see now has no duplicates (List.distinct was called on the argument list)? Please provide an example as I did below for your function. I may be wrong but until I see an example I stick to my amended solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Cool so many solutions for the same problem, guess I will share mine

```
let combineInts (ar : int list) = 
    let rec combine head (tail: int list) (remain: int list) =
        if tail.Length > 1 then
            (head, List.head tail) :: (combine head tail.Tail remain)
        else if remain.Length > 1 then
            (head, tail.Head) :: combine remain.Head remain.Tail remain.Tail
        else
            [(head, tail.Head)] 
    combine ar.Head ar.Tail ar.Tail
```

Not a big fan of

```
(head, List.head tail) :: combine head tail.Tail remain
```

So

```
let combineInts (ar : int list) = 
    let rec combine head (tail: int list) (remain: int list) (combinedSoFar: (int*int) list) =
        if tail.Length > 1 then
            combine head tail.Tail remain (combinedSoFar @ [(head, tail.Head)])
        else if remain.Length > 1 then
            combine remain.Head remain.Tail remain.Tail (combinedSoFar @ [(head, tail.Head)])
        else
            combinedSoFar @ [(head, tail.Head)]
    combine ar.Head ar.Tail ar.Tail []
```